# is there a way to add drag and drop in svg d3.js?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm working on a layout builder in SVG and want to add drag and drop and resizable features to it. my webpage contains a main canvas(SVG) and some nested SVG's in it. I want my nested SVG's (child SVGs you can say) to be draggable. How can I do that? I searched in JQuery we have draggable and resizable API but its not working in SVG. How can I achieve it in d3.js? any help would be preferred. thanks in advance.

Comment: Guess you won't find exact examples for what you're looking for. D3 usually deals with a single `<svg>`. Multiple nested ones is pretty uncommon. Instead, you will usually find a single `<svg>` with nested `<g>` groups inside.

Comment: isn't <g> and <svg> are kinda same things? I mean they both have the same functionality. but <svg> have more options than <g>

Comment: There are some differences, such as the `<defs>` section. But what I mean is only that it's uncommon, not impossible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mike Bostock's Circle Dragging example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e) should get you started. The bare minimum, comparable to jQuery, would be:

```
svg.selectAll("svg").call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged));

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d3.event.x)
    .attr("y", d3.event.y);
}
```

But better join the SVG elements to data objects first and then modify the data instead of the elements directly:

```
svg.selectAll("svg").data(elements)
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise();
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
    .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
}
```

To account for mouse pointer offset, and to turn the drag-and-drop into a rescale operation, you'll have to fill in the drag handler functions accordingly.