# Drag events not getting fired easily using d3-drag on svg elements

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

`drawAll` is a two dimensional array where `drawAll[i]` is an element/drawing containing all the strokes in that drawing. A stroke, represented as a string, is a series of 2D points that can be used to create a `<path>`.

I am trying to make each `.element` draggable to anywhere else in the `#canvas` svg. I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167251/is-there-a-way-to-add-drag-and-drop-in-svg-d3-js), but my elements are not getting dragged easily---I have to try dragging multiple times before the drag events are getting fired. I'm not sure what is going wrong or how the elements could be dragged easily. Thanks in advance. :)

`drawAll` example with two elements (containing only one stroke per element):

```
var drawAll = [["M6,239 C6,239 46,149 88,67 127,6 135,0 140,19 143,74 151,129 158,156 185,221 184,243 166,251 127,255 52,252 0,246"],["M113,15 C113,15 45,95 28,114 23,115 0,148 48,166 114,184 255,184 208,125 178,75 147,12 122,0"]];
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <svg id="canvas" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="400" width="400" viewbox="0 0 2000 2000"></svg>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function getData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var data;
        $.getJSON(Flask.url_for("data"))
        .done(function(json){
            data = json;

            var drawAll = [];
            var i, j;
            var temp1 = data;
            for (i in temp1){
                var temp2 = temp1[i];
                var drawOne = [];
                for (j in temp2){
                    var temp3 = temp2[j][0];
                    var temp4 = temp2[j][1];
                    var points = "";
                    for (k in temp3){
                        if(k == 0)
                        {
                            points = points + "M" + temp3[k] + ",";
                            points = points + temp4[k] + " ";
                            points = points + "C" + temp3[k] + ",";
                            points = points + temp4[k] + " ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            points = points + temp3[k] + ",";
                            points = points + temp4[k] + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    drawOne.push(points);
                }
                drawAll.push(drawOne);
            }
            resolve(drawAll);
            reject("Error in fetching JSON");
        });
    });
}

function draw(drawAll){
    var width = 2000;
    var spacing = 300;
    var x = -spacing;
    var temp = -spacing;
    var y = 0;
    var id = 0;

    var elements = d3.select("#canvas");
    var element = elements.selectAll("svg.element")
        .data(drawAll)
        .enter()
        .append("svg")
            .attr("class", "element")
            .attr("id", function(){
                return id++;
            })
            .attr("x", function(){
                if(x + spacing > width)
                    x = -spacing;
                x = x + spacing;
                return x;
            })
            .attr("y", function(){
                if(temp + spacing > width)
                {
                    temp = -spacing;
                    y = y + spacing;
                }
                temp = temp + spacing;
                return y;
            })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", function(d){
                    d3.select(this).raise();
                })
                .on("drag", function(d){
                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
                        .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
                })
                .on("end", function(d){

                }));
    element.selectAll("path .stroke")
        .data(function(d){
            return d;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "stroke")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return d;
        })
        .attr("style", "fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2;");

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(drawAll);
        reject("Error in drawing JSON");
    });
}

function runner(){
    return getData()
        .then(draw)
        .catch(function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        });
}

runner().catch(function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });
```

Comment: Your stroke-width in userspace is 2px, but you effectively scale that with 400/2000 = 0.2, so it comes out on screen as 0.4px. That is pretty narrow to hit with a pointer device. Do things get easier with wider strokes?

Comment: Thank you! :) That did solve the problem, but my drawings aren't as neat now. Anything you would like to suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [pointer-events](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) presentation attribute to tweak where events can be raised.

To hit a narrow stroke, you could also combine it with a wider, transparent line that is only there to catch the events:

```
var group = element.selectAll("g .stroke")
    .data(function(d){
        return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("style", "fill: none; stroke: black")
    .attr("class", "stroke");

group.append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d){
        return d;
    })
    .attr("style", "stroke-width: 10; stroke-linecap: round; opacity: 0");

group.append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d){
        return d;
    })
    .attr("style", "stroke-width: 2;");
```

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. :)